# App Insights 'join' that returns only the first result

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I have a job running hourly (at slightly different times) and logging metrics into Application Insights.

I want to trigger an alert based on the metrics from the *latest* job run.

```
let metrics = customMetrics | where ... | extend run = bin(timestamp, 1m);
let latestRun = metrics | top 1 by run desc;
metrics | join latestRun on run
```

Looking at `metrics` I can see this query should be returning 8 results. But it returns only the first of them. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, this is by design - the query language does not use inner joins by default, instead it uses ["innerunique" joins](https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Language-Reference/Tabular-operators/join-operator#default-join-flavor).

Switching to `join kind=inner` fixed my original query.